# How to input secure CVV number of credit card in watch app via dictation?

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

I have to enter CVV number of credit card in watch app designed on watch OS2 sdk via dictation.But number is printing as it is.
Not as secure keys.

```
let textChoices = ["123","124","236","456", "345", "Seriously, just order Pizza!!"]
    presentTextInputControllerWithSuggestions(textChoices,
        allowedInputMode: WKTextInputMode.Plain,
        completion: {(results) -> Void in
            if results != nil && results!.count > 0 { //selection made
                let aResult = results?[0] as? String
                    self.labelPrint.setText(aResult)


                    //{
                    //self.labelPrint.setText(aResult)
                //}
            }})
```

**Can anyone suggest how to make the numbers entered as secure keys?**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I created one demo for secure text entry in Apple Watch to accomplish my requirement.I think it would also help you. I uploaded code to my git account. Here I sharing link of Project Repo :

https://github.com/sagargondaliya/SecureTextInputForAppleWatch

Input Controller for Apple Watch

[image]